# How to retrieve a value sent by a controller in textbox?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I need to send a data from table to a view page. I have a database with table `settings` in which I have a tax value. I wrote a function to view the view page in my controller. I have a model file where I have a function to get the tax value. In my view page I need to display the content in a text box. How to do it?
This is my function in model page where I get the tax value .

```
public function get_settings()
 {
  $this->db->select('settings.id');
 $this->db->select('settings.company_tax14');
   $this->db->from('settings');
     $query = $this->db->get('settings');
        return $query->row(); 
 }
```

This is my controller page where I send the tax value to view page.

```
<?php
class Admin_service extends CI_Controller {
 public function add();
{

 $data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->get_settings();

        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service/add';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

}
}
?>
```

This is my view

```
<input type="text" value="tax_edit"/>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?= $settings->yourfieldname ?>"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $settings->company_tax14?>"/>
```

Comment: i am getting a white screen for this .

Comment: May there is no data being passed. Try to dump the `$settings` if has value, in your view dump the variable like this .
    `<?php var_dump($settings)?>`

You can also check first like this.
    `<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($settings->company_tax14) ? $settings->company_tax14 : ''?>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="<?= $settings->company_tax14 ?>"/>
```

Anything in controller you pass in array of data will be accessible using variable of the same name.

for ex - **Controller:**

```
$data['myself'] = "myname";
```

**View:**

```
echo $myself; // outputs myname
```